# python pandas DataFrame subplot in columns and rows

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, subplot

I would like to produce a subplot from data 4-column DataFrame into 2-rows and 2-columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000',periods=6, freq='1h'))
```

However, below will give a 4-row and 1-column plot

```
df.plot(use_index=False, title=f, subplots=True, sharey=True, figsize=(8, 6))
```

Comment: You should do it by hand, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, then something like `for i in df: plt.subplot(2,2,i+1);plt.plot(df[i]);`

Comment: @tesla1060 i suppose pandas could allow some sort of `figshape` argument...

Answer (score 14):

In current versions of Pandas, [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) features the `layout` keyword for this purpose.

```
df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2,2), ...)
```

Comment: This is the quickest implementation of OP's request

Answer (score 10):

cplcloud's answer works, but following code will give you a bit more structure so that you can start configuring more if you do not need the loop.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
fig.set_figheight(6)
fig.set_figwidth(8)
df[0].plot(ax=axes[0,0], style='r', label='Series'); axes[0,0].set_title(0)
df[1].plot(ax=axes[0,1]); axes[0,1].set_title(1)
df[2].plot(ax=axes[1,0]); axes[1,0].set_title(2)
df[3].plot(ax=axes[1,1]); axes[1,1].set_title(3)
fig.tight_layout()
```

Added some example on axis 0 to show how you can further configure it.